# Glass fish app server node agent not starting

Tags: glassfish, appserver

When i try to start node agent in my glassfish app server via putty i got the following warning

```
Apr 25, 2014 5:03:03 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.RMIClient warn
WARNING: channel.client_init_error
Apr 25, 2014 5:03:03 AM com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.RMIClient warn
WARNING: channel.client_init_error
```

and **finally "CLI137 Command start-node-agent failed." a timeout.**

The log file details are

```
2014-04-25T05:03:04.388-0500|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|ADM5801:Admin server channel crea
tion failed.|#]

[#|2014-04-25T05:03:04.396-0500|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.ee.enterprise.system.nodeagent|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|NAGT0014:Unexpected Node Agent ex
ception.
com.sun.appserv.server.ServerLifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to save stub to /opt/vendor/sunone/SDK/nodeagents/ACSNA-TEST/agent/config
/admch
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.AdminChannel.createRMIChannel(AdminChannel.java:111)
        at com.sun.enterprise.ee.nodeagent.NodeAgentMain.startup(NodeAgentMain.java:204)
        at com.sun.enterprise.ee.nodeagent.NodeAgentMain.main(NodeAgentMain.java:396)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to save stub to /opt/vendor/sunone/SDK/nodeagents/ACSNA-TEST/agent/config/admch
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.AdminChannel.saveStubToFile(AdminChannel.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.AdminChannel.createRMIChannel(AdminChannel.java:107)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/vendor/sunone/SDK/nodeagents/ACSNA-TEST/agent/config/admch (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.server.core.channel.AdminChannel.saveStubToFile(AdminChannel.java:348)
        ... 3 more
```

I am unable to figure out what excatly the issue is. I have got my permissions right. Please provide some inputs on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There IS obviously a permission problem. Make sure that the user your GF runs with has the permission to create a file in this path. Try to `touch` a file in this path in a shell.

Check that **every** directory in the path `/opt/vendor/sunone/SDK/nodeagents/ACSNA-TEST/agent/config/admch` has the execute right set for the GF user or its group (`chmod +x`).